# How to create fully custom module for sales person registration just like Add New Customer does in manage customer

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I am using the magento version 1.9.1.0 I want to add new module for sales person registration in magento admin, where admin can add sales person and edit it. I have create the menu for that but don't know how will I do. I want to the same as Customer->manage customer->Add New Customer. I want to add sales person in my case. I am new in magento. Also I have tried many on internet but I can't find the exact solution, so I have posted here.

I have tried the following

```
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#instructions
```

But I am confused, how will do the form and create attribues for database. I want to use only few filed just like name,username,password,email,address, country, city. So please help me to get this thing done.

Comment: This is a fairly complicated thing to try if you don't have a lot experience with Magento. There's a lot of resources out there now for learning Magento. If you tried that solution in the link then post the part that you don't understand and you'll be more likely to get help with it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have created a module and download. After that when I run this the backend page .phtml page is blank. I need to add some entry in config file as well or need. This silksoftware will show .phtml page. Please have a look www.silksoftware.com and try. Please let me know I have tried  from 5 new module in the link but the .phtml page is not showing, means the body of the page is blank, please help me.